# How do you monitor varnish cache inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, nagios

How do you monitor varnish cache inside a docker container?

I have found many tools on Google relating to this but we are focusing only on `nagios` and `new relic`.

Answer (score 2):

Varnish is monitored with what they call VSM. It's a file in your container. If you bind mount the folder where the files is, you can share the same folder / files in other containers that will be able to read it, and thus will be able to monitor your varnish instance.
See the note about [VSM and containers](https://varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/reference/vsm.html#vsm-and-containers) in varnish docs.
I have been able to launch a `varnishstat` with statistics in a container with varnish in the image, but no varnish running, like this:

```
docker run --rm -it \
       --entrypoint=/bin/sh \
       -v /var/lib/docker/overlay2/$hash/merged/usr/local/var/varnish/$hostname:/varnish \
      emgag/varnish:5.1.3 varnishstat -N /varnish/_.vsm
```